# Error in passing a parameter string with period to spring-boot backend

Tags: javascript, api, spring-boot, react-redux, axios

I am making an api call from my front end service to my backend service which works most of the time, however it breaks when there is a period in the form name. This is the api call my front end makes:

```js
static GetMetaDataInfo(returnName) {
  return axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/api/v1/filing-metadata/metadata/${returnName}`, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      }
    })
    .then(response => response.data)
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
}
```

My back-end controller is mapped to "/api/v1/filing-metadata" and the following request goes to "/metadata/{level1}/{level2}/{form_name}"

The return name is in the form of {Country}/{State}/{FormName}. Take "US\CO\CO DR-0251" as an example (this is an example that works when I make the call).

Using "US\CO\CO DR-0251" in the backend, {level1} corresponds to US, {level2} corresponds to CO, and {form_name} corresponds to CO DR-0251. By using this entire name, I query the database for a match, and return the data associated with this form name. 
My issue comes when a make the call with a form name that has a period in the name, for example: "US\NV\NV_TXR-02.01"

In this case the {form_name} when I make the request is "NV_TXR-02" instead of "NV_TXR-02.01" which fails to find a match when I query the data base. The form name is not something I can change, is there a way to keep the text that it is omitting when I make the call to my spring-boot back end?

Comment: Try adding a trailing slash to your request.

Comment: That worked, once I used the '/' at the end it didnt cut off everything after the period. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thank You to Steven B. for his comment, it turned out to be the solution to this question. I just needed to add a '/' character at the end of the url string. I added one at the front end code as well as the back end api and every case works now, even if they have periods.